# How to use CSS to maintain a 10px spacing between the yellow block and the black block below after the layout changes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am a self-learner of programming, and my English is not very good!
But there is a problem, I still try to describe the problem I encountered, I hope someone can help me.

At present, I have realized that when the mouse is scrolled to the specified position, the layout is converted, but I hope that when I switch to the yellow layout, the yellow block can still reserve a 10px distance from the black block below, but I have been in nav2, which is yellow Margin-bottom:10px is set in the block; I don’t know why the effect cannot be rendered!

Can someone tell me where I should set it?
Or is my CSS concept wrong?

Thank you for helping me. I want to thank you all for your attention to this issue.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollH=$(document).scrollTop();
    if(scrollH > 60){
      $('.nav').addClass('up');
      $('.nav2').addClass('down');
    }else if(scrollH < 90){
       $('.nav').removeClass('up');
       $('.nav2').removeClass('down');
    }
})
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav2.down {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
          animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after {
  content: ">";
  padding: 0px 8px;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after:last-child {
  display: none;
}
.nav2 .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 3px;
  order: 3;
}
.nav2 .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav2 .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #1768ac;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav.up {
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s forwards;
          animation: fadeout 1s forwards;
}
.nav .filter {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.nav .filter .item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.nav .category {
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
}
.nav .category .item {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.nav .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  order: 3;
}
.nav .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">LOGO</div>


<div class="nav">
  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="item">HOT</li>
    <li class="item">NEW</li>
 </ul>
  <ul class="category">
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="search">
    <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
    <input class="search_input" type="text" >
    <a  class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav2">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="item">index</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
  </ul>
   <div class="search">
      <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
      <input class="search_input" type="text" >
      <a  class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.lorem100Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because nav2 is a **position:fixed** element. When you mention an element as **fixed**, they are removed from the flow of the document and gets placed relative to the document based on top,left,right,bottom values.

That said, in-order to achieve the gap, you can place margin to the next element

```
.content {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hello~ Rohan 
Thank you for telling me!
But I listened to your suggestion, although margin-top:10px; is added to the content side,
but when this method is sliding, the black block and the yellow block will still look visually due to the relationship between the yellow block and the upper layer. In the end, it is still fit together, and it does not always maintain a 10px spacing regardless of whether it is scrolled or not. I don't know if there are other ways to achieve it? Thank you